# Safe way to rebind a key for only the duration of a function

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I am working on some code that does keyboard macros and minibuffer recursive edits. As a result, sometimes you need to exit a macro's recursive edit before the minibuffer. This can be confusing for the user, so I want to rebind "RET" to exit the recursive macro while in the minibuffer. This was easily accomplished as part of the recursive macro calling with the following example code:

```
(defun config:macro-query (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  ;; Temporarily bind what is normally C-M-c (exit-recursive-edit) to RET, so
  ;; RET will work in the spawned minibuffer.
  (cl-flet ((internal-exit ()
              (interactive)
              (exit-recursive-edit)))
    (let* ((prompt (if arg (read-from-minibuffer "PROMPT: ") "Input: "))
           (input (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
                      (lambda ()
                        (substitute-key-definition 'exit-minibuffer
                                                   #'internal-exit
                                                   minibuffer-local-map)
                        (kbd-macro-query t))
                    (read-from-minibuffer prompt))))
      (substitute-key-definition #'internal-exit 'exit-minibuffer
                                 minibuffer-local-map)
      (unless (string= "" input) (insert input)))))
```

However, I'm concerned that it's unsafe. I probably need some way to ensure that the last substitute-key-definition is guaranteed to run (unwind-protect, I suppose) even if something bad happens and the user aborts. But beyond that, I'm wondering if there's an officially-blessed way to do this. I wasn't able to find anything in basic searches, but I can't be the first person to have the problem of "I want to rebind this key, but only for the duration of , after which it should go back to what it was before". Does emacs have a more rigorous, built-in way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set-transient-map is a native-compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.

(set-transient-map MAP &optional KEEP-PRED ON-EXIT MESSAGE TIMEOUT)

Set MAP as a temporary keymap taking precedence over other keymaps.
Normally, MAP is used only once, to look up the very next key.
However, if the optional argument KEEP-PRED is t, MAP stays
active if a key from MAP is used.  KEEP-PRED can also be a
function of no arguments: it is called from ‘pre-command-hook’ and
if it returns non-nil, then MAP stays active.

Optional arg ON-EXIT, if non-nil, specifies a function that is
called, with no arguments, after MAP is deactivated.

Optional arg MESSAGE, if non-nil, requests display of an informative
message after activating the transient map.  If MESSAGE is a string,
it specifies the format string for the message to display, and the %k
specifier in the string is replaced with the list of keys from the
transient map.  Any other non-nil value of MESSAGE means to use the
message format string "Repeat with %k".  Upon deactivating the map,
the displayed message will be cleared out.

Optional arg TIMEOUT, if non-nil, should be a number specifying the
number of seconds of idle time after which the map is deactivated.
The variable ‘set-transient-map-timeout’, if non-nil, overrides the
value of TIMEOUT.

This function uses ‘overriding-terminal-local-map’, which takes precedence
over all other keymaps.  As usual, if no match for a key is found in MAP,
the normal key lookup sequence then continues.

This returns an "exit function", which can be called with no argument
to deactivate this transient map, regardless of KEEP-PRED.
```

n.b. The MESSAGE and TIMEOUT arguments were added in Emacs 29.1.

Comment: Thanks! keep-pred should do exactly what I need here. Wonder how I missed that the first time around! I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation for it.